# Convert table Columns into a Hierarchy structure and accordingly change other columns count and percentage

Tags: sql, pyspark, pivot, unpivot

I have a table in the below format.

| Nhead | Rhead | Ghead | Fhead | Year | Month | Cover_count | Total_Count | Per_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d | 2 | 2021 | 20 | 30 | 66.66 |
| a | f | g | h | 2 | 2021 | 40 | 60 | 66.66 |
| a | f | g | h | 3 | 2021 | 80 | 90 | 88.88 |
| w | x | y | z | 3 | 2021 | 10 | 20 | 50 |

I want table output as

| Head | Name | year | Month | cover_count | Total_count | Per_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nhead | a | 2 | 2021 | 60 | 90 | 66.66 |
| Rhead | b | 2 | 2021 | 20 | 30 | 66.66 |
| Rhead | f | 2 | 2021 | 40 | 60 | 66.66 |
| Ghead | c | 2 | 2021 | 20 | 30 | 66.66 |
| Ghead | g | 2 | 2021 | 40 | 60 | 66.66 |
| Fhead | d | 2 | 2021 | 20 | 30 | 66.66 |
| Fhead | h | 2 | 2021 | 40 | 60 | 66.66 |
| Nhead | a | 3 | 2021 | 80 | 90 | 88.88 |
| Rhead | f | 3 | 2021 | 80 | 90 | 88.88 |
| Ghead | g | 3 | 2021 | 80 | 30 | 88.88 |
| Fhead | h | 3 | 2021 | 80 | 30 | 88.88 |
| Nhead | w | 3 | 2021 | 10 | 20 | 50 |

Please help me with this query

Comment: I am using the below query---select Head,Name,year,Month,cover_count,Total_count,Per_Count from(
select Nhead,Rhead,Ghead ,Fhead ,Year ,Month ,Cover_count, Total_Count, Per_count from tbl) src
unpivot(Name for Head in(Nhead,Rhead,Ghead ,Fhead)pvt1      but it is throwing errror                   ParseException: 
mismatched input 'for' expecting {')', ',', '-'}(line 1, pos 33)

Comment: is it because the column Rhead has few null values ?

Comment: anyone please answer